# ActionScript library for drawing, resizing, moving shapes and text?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, drawing

I know Sprite.graphics is pretty easy to use, but I was wondering if there is any ready made libraries for drawing, resizing, moving, layering, etc.. of various display elements? Also, stuff like tool selection, maybe some effects, premade shapes. Anything you would recommend?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should look into [Graffiti](http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/) and/or [ASDraw](http://code.google.com/p/asdraw/).

Comment: I highly recommend Graffiti as well, it rocks!

Comment: I looked at Graffiti. It doesn't seem to have object selection tool for other than text, subsequently you can't move objects and it doesn't have resize and rotate handles. Just using new Sprite().graphics.drawRect wouldn't suffice. I looked briefly at ASDraw but it doesn't seem active or documented. Anything else?

Comment: @Ska: I haven't tried, but here http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/beta/ they say "Multi-Object Selection - You can now select, modify, move and delete multiple objects on the canvas at once". But maybe, being a beta, you can use it at your own risk.

Comment: Ok, this looks more interesting, however if you look at the stuff missing from beta1 it is pretty crucial and they haven't had an update in a year. If this was an open source project I'd contribute and develop missing stuff, but for the paid product I'd expect it to be there.